# Music visualizer and window font issue

Tags: windows-10, fonts

About a week ago, I tried to get No Man's Sky font as a default on my PC, but it looked terrible and I switched back. I [followed this tutorial to change the default](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/change-default-font-windows-10):.

I reset the settings back to defaults in the Control Panel > Fonts > Font Settings

However, there is still an issue, for example:

[image: The 's' in the Music Visualiser has some kind of tail on it, but none on the actual file]

[image: The Color Management window now has font in Bold and it also has incorrect font size (increased). Some of the buttons are beyond the window borders as a result]

[image: The pop-up in Visual Studio also has incorrect font]

Comment: Good thing you took a back up of your registry, ...yea?

Comment: Wow I completely forgot I had done that! Yes, that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed all the steps in the guide you posted, you should have exported your Registry to a .reg file. Double-click that registry export to restore it back to what it was before you made any changes.

For anyone that made this change **without** exporting their Registry first, you can create a fix .reg file with the following lines:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"="segoeui.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"="seguibl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"="seguibli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"="segoeuib.ttf"
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuiz.ttf"
"Segoe UI Emoji (TrueType)"="seguiemj.ttf"
"Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"="seguihis.ttf"
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"="segoeuii.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"="segoeuil.ttf"
"Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"="seguili.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"="seguisb.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"="seguisbi.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"="segoeuisl.ttf"
"Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"="seguisli.ttf"
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"="seguisym.ttf"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"=-
```

Paste that into `Notepad.exe` or similar and save as `"SegoeUIFontFix.reg"`. Double-click the file to reset the Segoe UI font to default settings.